# handle toString NullPointException, even after checking for !null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting frequent crash with

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phocast/com.example.phocast.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
```

AndroidStudio is also showing that `Method invocation .toString may produce NullPointException`

My code is:

```
public class SunFragment extends Fragment {

  ArrayList<Object> sunsList;
  Typeface sunfont;
  Double Dlat;
  Double Dlang;

  private AdView mAdView;

  //to be called by the MainActivity
  public SunFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
  public String TAG = "SunFragment";
  public String location;//="No location name found";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
      } else {
      location = "";
    }
  }
```

Since I am already checking for `savedInstanceState`, what else I can check?

Comment: It looks like calling `.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME)` on the `savedInstanceState` is returning null.

Comment: `savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME)` is null. put null check on the whole expression.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried to check if that charsequence not null too, and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `savedInstance` is nil, but calling the `toString` method on the result of `getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME)` that hasn't been null checked.

You should try something like this

```
if (savedInstance != null && savedInstance.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME) != null)
   location = savedInstance.getCharsequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not setting success charSecuence onto bundle.

Should be something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME, location);
    }
```

Carefully if you implement `protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` Its a different method!